# Sum multiple columns showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Is it possible to total two columns, however still show all of the results? At the moment, If i sum one of the columns in the select statement (e.g. sum(sales_amount), it only 1 line of the results show

```
SALES_ID    EMPLOYEE_ID PRODUCT_ID  SALES_AMOUNT    QUANTITY    DATE    
1           123148      4578947          80            1    01/01/2018
2           123148      5124578          80            1    01/01/2018
```

I want to keep the two results shown above, however an extra line created showing a total of 160 under the sales_amount, quantity of 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is arguably bad SQL because the semantics of the last row is different from the others. (Rows and columns should be logically interchangeable.) That said, as I write this, I see that @Gordon-Linoff has just given the answer that I was going to give. Still, I would argue that such aggregations should be separate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in this case probably `union all`:

```
select SALES_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, SALES_AMOUNT, QUANTITY, DATE  
from t
union all
select NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(sales_amount), sum(quantity), date
from t
group by date;
```

If your data is the result of an aggregation query, then `rollup` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Select SALES_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, PRODUCT_ID,SALES_AMOUNT ,QUANTITY, DATE ,
(SALES_AMOUNT* QUANTITY) AS TOTAL FROM (YOUR TABLE NAME)

If you use this query, the amount is multiplied by the quantity for each row and displayed in the new column